# HTML webform button to add text to an email field

Tags: html, webforms

I have a pretty basic webform: First, Last, email.

I would like to create options/buttons that add text to the email field. Predetermined buttons that contain: @yahoo.com, @gmail.com, etc. Whether it's just a link/text or an actual button. Can't figure it out!

Thank you!

Billy

Comment: What have you tried?  This sounds like basic JavaScript.  You can respond to a button click and update the value of an input element.  Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a select box whose chosen value can be supplied to textbox using js/jquery, and add the options whenever you need to add more mail engines; that would help u in long run as adding button u would have compromise with ui if u need to add more search engines

Answer (score 1):

A **select** would look better according to me, as used on [fakemailgenerator](http://fakemailgenerator.com)

```
<select name="email-domain">
    <option value="gmail">@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="yahoo">@yahoo.com</option>
    <option value="outlook">@outlook.com</option>
</select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle snippet to see working example
https://jsfiddle.net/d713yvbf/